# Sonata Admin - filter in header of table

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony4, symfony-sonata

is there any way to show basic filter (with Sonata Admin Bundle and Symfony 4) just below title in table list view?

Something like in this picture? [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX6YK.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to achieve this via configuration. You will have to make extension for this thing, but we cant do this for you. If your question is if there is a default way of doing this? Then answer is NO there isnt, but I think it is possible with extension.